# Convert Vector to HTML5 Canvas (DXF to Canvas coordinates)

Tags: java, html, canvas, raster, dxf

Is there a way to take DXF drawings and create the HTML5 code that will draw the image onto the canvas?

Answer (score 0):

I'm searching for same thing, what I found until now, is that I have to convert the DXF file to .OBJ, I need to display the 3D object in HTML5 canvas using WebGL.
Here is a useful link on OBJ loader (http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/webgl_loader_obj.html)
But I'm still searching for a way to convert the DXF to OBJ.